# What am I doing wrong in this SendInput snippet?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, sendinput

Just experimenting with some WinAPI stuff. I have a C# console app that uses `SendInput` to simulate a `keydown` and `keyup` events of some keyboard key. It's not working though, maybe I'm doing something stupid, the key isn't being sent, not sure what am I missing - (trying to send a "W", sleep for 5 secs, open up some text editor to see the letter magically there):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        input.type = (int)InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.U.ki.wScan = 0;
        input.U.ki.time = 0;
        input.U.ki.dwExtraInfo = UIntPtr.Zero;
        input.U.ki.wVk = VirtualKeyShort.KEY_W;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYDOWN;
        NativeCalls.SendInput(1, new INPUT[] { input }, INPUT.Size);

        input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;
        NativeCalls.SendInput(1, new INPUT[] { input }, INPUT.Size);

        return;
}
```

**Definitions:**

```
public static class NativeCalls
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SendInput(
    uint nInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INPUT
{
    internal uint type;
    internal InputUnion U;
    internal static int Size
    {
        get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct InputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    internal VirtualKeyShort wVk;
    internal ScanCodeShort wScan;
    internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
    internal int time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[Flags]
internal enum KEYEVENTF : uint
{
    KEYDOWN = 0x0000,
    EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
    KEYUP = 0x0002,
    SCANCODE = 0x0008,
    UNICODE = 0x0004
}

internal enum InputType { INPUT_MOUSE = 0, INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1, INPUT_HARDWARE = 2 }

internal enum VirtualKeyShort : short
{
    // keys
    KEY_W = 0x57,
    // more keys
}
```

What am I doing wrong? why is the key not being sent?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your union declaration is incomplete. Because of that, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))` returns an incorrect value. You do at least need to define the `MOUSEINPUT` part of the `INPUT` union since that has the largest size. The [`pinvoke.net`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/INPUT.html) declaration should suffice.

I expect that `SendInput` would have told you of the problem had you checked the return value. I expect that `SendInput` returns `false`, and then a call to `GetLastError` should yield `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Of course, you should not call `GetLastError` directly. Use `SetLastError = true`, and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`. You simply have to perform accurate error checking when you call Win32 API functions.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
...
```

This part of the declaration is wrong at pinvoke.net where they omit `SetLastError`.

You are using `SendInput` in a clumsy way. The `SendInput` function exists so that you can place multiple input messages in the queue without having them interleaved by others. The documentation makes this clear when it discusses `SendInput` in relation to the now deprecated `keybd_event` and `mouse_event` functions. Call `SendInput` once passing an array of length 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did take the definition from pinvoke site. But I thought I could get rid of the mouse stuff since I don't need it. But it seems it has to be there. And yes you're right about the way I'm using it, since this is the first time... :)

Comment: Thanks - it appears that I only had to add the rest of the missing definitions (mouse and hardware stuff) - why must they be there if I'm not gonna use them?

Comment: and, when should I call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()?

Comment: I explain that right at the start. Without them there, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))` produces an incorrect value. And `SendInput` decides that it does not understand what you are sending it. As soon as you start sending arrays of `INPUT`, then the memory layout has to be right.

Comment: Call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` when `SendInput` returns `false` (i.e. zero). That's called out in the docs for `SendInput`.

Comment: right - I read that and understood why I do need them. But then I forgot that I read them lol :)